# why SQL inner join returns empty result in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

can you please check why this code is returning me empty result in laravel.
i am trying to fetch nations name based upon nation id in teachers table.

```
public function edit(Teacher $teacher)
{

  $teachers= DB::table('teachers','nations')
  ->join('nations', 'teachers.nation_id', '=', 'nations.id')
  ->select('teachers.*')
  ->where('teachers.id',$teacher->id)
  ->first();

return view('teachers.create',['teachers' => $teachers]);
}
```

Comment: `dd($teacher->id)` and see if you're getting id or not

Comment: @Iftikharuddin it returns id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code

```
public function edit(Teacher $teacher)
{
  $teachers= DB::table('teachers')
    ->join('nations', 'teachers.nation_id', '=', 'nations.id')
    ->select('teachers.*','nations.name')
    ->where('teachers.id','=',$teacher->id)
    ->first();

  return view('teachers.create',['teachers' => $teachers]);
}
```

Comment: then there is no rows having the matched id's

Comment: yes it returns all id's and if i remove join it returns correct result, but with join null.

Comment: check the join variables nation_id and id, check whether at least one row having similar values in those tables

Comment: SQL: select `teachers`.*, `nations`.`name` from `teachers` inner join `nations` on `teachers`.`nation_id` = `nations`.`id` where `teachers`.`id` = 911 limit 1)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use the query builder to perform such a not complex query?

You can achieve this easier if you add a relationship method in your `Teacher` model.

So in your `Teacher` class add the following:

```
public function nation() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Nation::class);
}
```

Then in your controller you can use it like this:

```
$teacher->nation;
```

Comment: i have already tried Eloquent query builder it works fine, but i have complex queries ahead, so i will stick with sql query builder as it is fast.

Comment: SQL: select `teachers`.*, `nations`.`name` from `teachers` inner join `nations` on `teachers`.`nation_id` = `nations`.`id` where `teachers`.`id` = 911 limit 1)

Answer (score 1):

In case you allowed in teachers table for nation_id to be empty value or null,
you need to use left join to still have all records from teachers table:

```
public function edit(Teacher $teacher)
{

  $teachers= DB::table('teachers','nations')
  ->leftJoin('nations', 'teachers.nation_id', '=', 'nations.id')
  ->select('teachers.*', 'nations.name')
  ->where('teachers.id',$teacher->id)
  ->first();
  return view('teachers.create',['teachers' => $teachers]);
}
```

Comment: error: SQL: select `teachers`.*, `nations`.`name` from `teachers` left join `nations` on `teachers`.`nation_id` = `nations`.`id` where `teachers`.`id` = 915 limit 1

Comment: What's title of column for nation name in database schema?

Comment: name is; nations.name

Comment: You could use `->select(DB::raw('teachers.id, teachers.name, nations.name'))`